# Can nested class instantiate outer class?

Tags: java, class, recursion, nested, instantiation

Say there is a nested class within an outer class class; Can that nested class instantiate an instance of the outer class within itself?

If the outer class instantiates an instance of an inner class within itself, which in turn instantiates an instance of the outer class within the inner class, would this cause an infinite recursion?

Comment: the real question is, why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: Have you tried it? Also, why would this be different from creating a new instance of class A inside the constructor of A?

Comment: Downvoted because this shows no research effort. You could have tried this yourself first.

Comment: I ask because I'm working with the android framework and from viewing the surface-view example I see a nested Thread class is instantiated within its container class. It get a bit more complicated because the Thread class has its own stack (I believe).

Comment: Classes don't have stacks my friend. The thread as an entity has a stack.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you meant the below, then yes, it **will** lead to a `StackOverflowError`.

```
public class Outer {

    public Outer() {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
    }

    private class Inner {
        public Inner() {
            Outer outer = new Outer();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
    }
}
```

The above prints:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.adarshr.Outer.<init>(Outer.java:6)
    at com.adarshr.Outer$Inner.<init>(Outer.java:12)
    at com.adarshr.Outer.<init>(Outer.java:7)
    at com.adarshr.Outer$Inner.<init>(Outer.java:12)
    at com.adarshr.Outer.<init>(Outer.java:7)
    at com.adarshr.Outer$Inner.<init>(Outer.java:12)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a *static* inner class you should be able to do so, as the outer class is really just acting as a namespace- that is, it's legal to have existing instances of the inner class without an existing instance of the outer class, so yes.

If the inner class not static, it can only exist (can only be instantiated) in the context of its enclosing class. So you'd have to have the outer created first in order to create the inner, so no.

Comment: +1 for static. But as a good design one must avoid instantiating or referring to the outer class from the inner class.

Comment: Agreed, but then again I think that we're even discussing this question pretty much rules out the possibility we'd be talking about good design.

Comment: Oh certainly. Was just making a general point. Some day someone may come across this page trying to instantiating an outer class and will find your solution. Just want that person to bear in mind the evils of this new power he will find then. :D